# Hepaitits B vaccination schedule for children

Tags: vaccination

I am trying to understand the two-dose Hep B vaccination for children. It appears that in the UK, while not part of standard NHS care, the two-dose schedule is approved for those aged 1 and older (cf. the "[green book](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/503768/2905115_Green_Book_Chapter_18_v3_0W.PDF)"). In the US the [CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/mm4912a5.htm) only approves the two-dose schedule for children 11 and over. What evidence are these decisions based on?

Answer (score 2):

The NHS only advises Hepatitis B vaccination to young children when they are at a [high risk](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/vaccinations/pages/childhood-vaccination-schedule.aspx) of exposure. This means when the [mother is infected and contagious](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/vaccinations/Pages/hepatitis-b-vaccine.aspx), or there are close relatives with the disease.  Otherwise vaccination is optional.

The CDC recommends hepatitis B vaccination at [birth](http://www.cdc.gov/hepatitis/hbv/vaccchildren.htm), [changing](http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/rr5416a1.htm) from the policy of vaccinating those at risk.

The [WHO](http://www.who.int/immunization/diseases/hepatitisB/en/) also recommends vaccination from birth so the different stance taken by the NHS may be political or economic..

Comment: I understand that, I was asking about the two-dose schedule and why only the UK approves it for young children.

Comment: Cost benefit analyses, and politicians have stopped it so far. But it's been looked at to bring the UK in line with other countries.  http://www.pulsetoday.co.uk/clinical/immunisation/government-advisors-consider-hep-b-jab-for-infant-schedule/20007341.fullarticle

Comment: I'm also not sure how this fully answers the question - which is essentially about why the two-dose schedule is only approved for children 11 years and older by the CDC, as I understand it. If this has changed, maybe you could make this clearer in your second paragraph?